# Is it possible to get jersey to read json variables our of a request body without using a bean?

Tags: json, jersey

In jersey a Java bean can be auto-deserialized from within a request body but what if I want to read a parameter without creating a special type. Is it possible to do this using annotations.

My current code is:

```
public class RequestData {
    String param;
}

...

public Response readData(RequestData data) {
    data.getParam();
    ...
}
```

I want it to be something like:

```
public Response readData(@RequestParam("param") String param) {
    ...
}
```

If its not already clear the input JSON is:

```
{
    "param":"some value"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of your input JSON is `Map<String, String>` so if you want to have undifferentiated input you could use that as your request parameter and read the values that you require.

Note that `@RequestParam` looks at the request parameters and not the body, so it's a different beast.

Comment: Is there a way to setup something like BodyParam? I think its more elegant not to have to get that string from a map.

Comment: You *could*, by writing a provider which read the body and parsed it in to a Map then served the named value.  However, if you do this then the body will not be available to your resources so I'd not go down this route.  Using a `Map` is going to be safer in terms of future extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You do this by letting Jersey pass you String as is (as per annotations), and then data-bind it using Jackson `ObjectMapper` (thing Jersey uses internally for JSON binding):

```
Map<String,Object> map = objectMapper.readValue(param, Map.class);
```

to get access to `ObjectMapper`, you can use JAX-RS injection annotation (`@Context` I think?) in the resource class:

```
@Context
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
```